# How to find out the Power of $x(t)$?

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

I am studying signals and system.

I learned that
\begin{align}
P&=\lim_{L\to\infty} \frac 1{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} |x(t)|^2 dt\\
P&=\frac 1{T} \int_{<T>} |x(t)|^2 dt ~~~\mbox{, P could be solved with this easier equation when } x(t) \mbox{ is periodic.}
\end{align}

---

I made a artificial signal myself like the following.
\begin{align}
x(t)&=t &x&\in(0, T)\\
x(t+T)&=x(t) &x&\in(-\infty, \infty)
\end{align}

---

using the definition of $P$,

\begin{align}
P &= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L} \left(\int_{-L}^0 |t+T|^2 dt + \int_0^L |t|^2 dt \right)\\
&= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L} \left(\left[\frac{(t+T)^3}{3}\right]^0_{-L} + \left[ \frac{t^3}{3} \right]_0^L\right)\\
&= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L} \left(\frac{T^3 - (T-L)^3}{3}+\frac{L^3}3\right)\\
&= \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{1}{2L} \cdot \frac{3T^2L-3TL^2+2L^3}{3}\\
&= \lim_{L\to\infty} \left( \frac{T^2}{2}-\frac{TL}{2}+\frac{L^2}{3} \right)=\infty
\end{align}

---

using the modified equation because $x(t)$ is periodic,

\begin{align}
P &= \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T |t|^2 dt \\
&= \frac{1}{T} \left[\frac{t^3}{3}\right]^T_0\\
&= \frac{T^2}{3}
\end{align}

---

I felt so weird. What's wrong with my process. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: You don't take into account the periodicity of the signal; in your calculation, the signal grows without bounds when $L$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I thought a lot. Thanks to your hint, i got something. Thank you.